# How do I teach myself mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, advice, learning

I am looking for a rough guideline of the steps I need to take in order to gain an advanced understanding of the theory and applications of mathematics. What skills would I need to perfect in order to transition from my current (relatively) low level understanding to that of something close to a Master's graduate?

I'm by no means ignorant to the difficulty of this task, I'm fully aware that it will take multiple years to complete. Just simply seeking advice :)

Comment: In principle the same qualities as for everything else, say, for learning a foreign language. Grammar, vocabulary, exercises, practice, etc.

Comment: Doing a maths degree sounds like it might do the job.

Comment: The Open University is worth a look if you are in the UK, but what suits will depend on your circumstances and finances...  http://www.open.ac.uk/courses/maths/degrees/bsc-mathematics-q31

Comment: In terms of just building an understanding - watching YouTube videos and reading books is really, really helpful. If you get stuck with things (which everyone does from time to time) - you can always ask questions here and there are many people happy to point you in the right direction (just make sure the question obviously has context and contains your current progress so people don't down-vote the question etc etc). If you don't understand a particular topic - **make it your mission to understand**. That's really how you progress! Mathematics can be beautiful at higher levels - so enjoy it!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yeah that does seem like the most optimal approach, however I'm not sure as to where i would source this knowledge from. Are there any good books, or any other media that you would recommend?

Comment: @Paul Sadly that isn't a possibility at the moment, I am 16 and currently have no way of funding such venture, yet.

Comment: @MartinHansen I've looked into the Open University, and I hope to enroll onto a course there in the future if I am unable to attend a proper institution. Thanks for your recommendation.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Thank you for your recommendation. I find that YouTube is the easiest when it comes to that really, books take a while to read, and sometimes time is a stringent resource at times. Do you know any good YouTube channels?

Comment: "Are there any good books, or any other media that you would recommend? " For a foreign language and/or mathematics? No problem. First of all, an ordinary grammar does it well. Just chose a book on calculus, or linear algebra from the recommendations of this site.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say exactly what level you're starting at, but let's say you only know elementary arithmetic.

Then the main pre-university subjects would be:

- algebra
- geometry
- trigonometry
- vector and analytic geometry
- calculus

At university level, the central subjects are algebra and analysis, but many other subjects branch out from these. For the undergraduate university level, the schedules from the Cambridge undergraduate course in mathematics will give you a good idea of what there is to study.

See here: https://www-wp.maths.cam.ac.uk/documents/schedules.pdf/

Comment: That document you provided appears to be very helpful, I'm sure it will be useful when I reach that stage. Thank you for the list you provided, would you recommend any books that pair well with those subjects?

Comment: You should edit your question to better specify your current level of knowledge. What have you studied, and how would you describe your degree of mastery of that material?

Comment: @Borys, if you look at the schedules, eg on the page labelled as $6$, headed "IA Groups", you'll see that each course has a list of recommended books. I can't personally tell you how useful they are, but it's a starting point. It's worth noting: the way Cambridge teaches doesn't involve any mandatory books. You should be able to cover exactly this content by reading lecture notes and completing example sheets. Dexter Chua has famously compiled a set of very good lecture notes, and you can find others online - eg, Oscar Randall-Williams publishes his Groups notes on his own website.

Comment: Yeah that is actually very useful haha. I'll keep the teaching method noted. I'll have a look into those lecture notes at some point. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you applied to engineering. I did aircraft engineering, but naval or architecture are also good disciplines.

If you are not ready, then high school textbooks. You can probably do more than 10 pages daily or 100 pages weekly and while you progress, you will also learn do discern between good and bad pieces of information as presented in the textbooks.

While at it, I recommend high school physics as well. Mechanics, dynamics, fluids and electricity. Optics and quantum physics tend to be too difficult and I would skip them.

Mathematics is about developing a sense of right and wrong out of true and false statements and implications. Go slow, use alternative sources, even online courses. Sometimes you will need to study history of mathematics, some other times an internet reference will be enough. If you still don’t get it, mark it as “rework” and get over it. Is important to compile your own list of misunderstandings and questions. A later review will help you understand yourself better, by the way the mathematics eases into your mind. Some obvious answers will surprise you for even asking the question, while some other misunderstandings will follow you. Don’t get stuck because you don’t understand. You need to ask to be answered. Enjoy!

Comment: Sadly I can't apply to a university course until i turn 18, If i go down that path I would also pick aerospace engineering too. Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: With a further consideration of your answer, i wanna ask a question. Do you know any good books that include a good portion of those subjects?

Comment: Most of the math books I know are good, including textbooks. I do teach math so my appreciation won’t be useful to you since I know the topics already. To learn math not easy because it presents itself as a long list of definitions. I would say high school textbooks are the closest you could get. I personally developed a taste for mathematics in high school when studying mechanics (inclined plane gave me access to vectors, motion made me use quadratics, circular motion gave me complex numbers, then electricity gave me sine function, Fourier transform, differential calculus).

Comment: Without physics I wouldn’t have learned math. When I look back at the problems in a textbook, I discover the effort to make the numbers close to real life and I remember clearly that back then the numbers made no sense to me. I remember how I burned a transistor in physics, despite my prior learning. So what you will be facing is your own inertia at accepting new information (that will come to you as self-confirmation that the textbook is badly written, which unfortunately in some instances is true).

Comment: Math is simple: first you count, then you learn to multiply and divide, then fractions, then signed(!) integers, radicals help with like terms, linear equations, 2x2 systems, linear functions, quadratic, min/max, limits, continuity, differentiability. In between there is Euclidean geometry, polynomials, logarithms, trigonometry, complex numbers, Euclidean vectors, combinatorics. That’s it.

Comment: Actually the only reason why I'm learning mathematics is to be able to have a solid understanding of Physics. It seems like going down the route of taking it on as a subject at school is probably the best choice going forward. As a sidenote, how hard is aeronautic engineering?

Comment: @Borys, if you want to do physics or engineering, I wouldn't worry too much about having the level of understanding of maths of a master's graduate. Most people with maths degrees don't have that level of understanding, let alone most engineers! Most of the content in eg the Cambridge schedules is completely inapplicable to physics or understanding physics. If you're planning to go into higher education for engineering, you should just make sure you know the requirements and keep doing maths in school for now. Any maths you need will be taught to you when it becomes required.